# CSS: reducing line spacing of text?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, pagelines

I am having difficulty reducing the spacing between lines of text with CSS line-height (or height - I've tried both).

I have a small bit of text and the spacing is off. I've tried modifying the styles that (appear to) apply, and also enclosing the text in a `<span>...</span>` and explicitly declaring the style. Nothing seems to work.

The site is a Wordpress site using the Pagelines "lite" theme. The URL is http://stage.dsthree.com and the issue is on the front page (you can see it in the fourth column of text, just below the "email subscribe" box in the small text - the line spacing for that text is off. This site will not allow me to post a screenshot, as I am new here.

I've reduced the line-height to 1% and to 1px to no effect.

Any help, directions or suggestions on how to reduce the whitespace is much appreciated!

Comment: Post some code. Give the full context of how the HTML is structured for the text you're trying to adjust. Other than a `<span>` is the text in any other element? A `<p>`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Inline elements don't honour properties such as `line-height`; they take on the line height of the nearest block parent.

See [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/cV94W/)

Solution: remove the line-height from the body, or turn the span into a block (i.e. make it a div; don't give `display:block` to the span).

Comment: This solved it. Making it a <div> gave me the control of line-height that I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 21):

Add `display:block` & remove `height`.

```
<span style="font-size: 75%; line-height: 16px; display:block">blog posts & occasional updates (updates max 1 every 14 days)</span>
```

You learn more about `display:block` property **[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643424/why-do-you-put-a-displayblock-on-an-a-tag-that-is-inside-a-list)**.

Comment: you should probably explain to him why adding display block helps with the span. That would definitively make your answer much more useful. Hope you don't mind me suggesting.

Comment: And you shouldn't put `display:block` on a span. It serves no useful purpose, and I classify this as element abuse. Turn it into a div instead.

Comment: Thanks! as it turned out, turning it into a <div> made it work fine.

Comment: @user2649496 you are a day Savoir, by using `<div>` + `line-hieght:1 !important` solved my problem. I was using my text in `<b>` tag but was not working so thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have a `line-height: 21px;`
In the body. Remove this, and it should work.

Comment: I can't remove the line-height in the body as it applies to so many other elements. I need to over-ride it for this text...but thanks!

Comment: I tested it in webdev and it worked fine, but glad you have fixed it anyhow.