# Why line-height is ignored in a span tag and works in div tag?

Tags: css

Look at the following example:
[CSS: reducing line spacing of text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18151124/css-reducing-line-spacing-of-text)

I've tried and the CSS property line height is almost ignored if put into a span element. Why?
Why do I need to display it as a block to make line-height work?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9609227/css-inline-elements-ignoring-line-height

Comment: I think about line-height as a property of wrapped text lines instead of height of boxes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On block level elements, the line-height CSS property specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element.

On non-replaced inline elements, line-height specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height.

On replaced inline elements, like buttons or other input element, line-height has no effect.

Src: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/line-height

Comment: Warning: That's not quite what the CSS 2.1 spec says. It says "On a block container element whose content is composed of inline-level elements, 'line-height' specifies the minimal height of line boxes within the element." An element that is `inline-block` and has inline-level children meets the spec's definition, but not the MDN definition.

Comment: @Alohci: it's not very clear to me.. can you advice something to read?

Comment: @Alohci: from the following link it seems that line-height works on a p tag but not in a span tag: http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/line-height

Comment: @Sam - Thet's not correct. But line-height does different things. Span is a non-replaced inline element (by default) so "'line-height' specifies the height that is used in the calculation of the line box height." In fairness, that's pretty vague, but the details get quite complicated. Think of it like this. Each line-box must be tall enough to contain the full line-height of all the spans which are placed on that line, as well as an extra span like element (called a strut) which is the height of the line-height setting on the p element...

Comment: ... Vertical alignment causes a whole bunch of extra and quite subtle complications but that's essentially it.