# Move <a> tag to a new line without <br>

Tags: html, css

I would like to move each `<a>` to a new line without using `<br>`.

```
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643424/why-do-you-put-a-displayblock-on-an-a-tag-that-is-inside-a-list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `display: block` an all anchor tags to move them to their own line:

```
.redirects a {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

you need to reset the display to a block level value, or float and clear or reset BFCand size it.

there is many ways, just use the one that fits your needs best:

block

```css
a {display:block;background:grey}
```

```html
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

table

```css
a {display:table;background:gray}
```

```html
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

flex ?

```css
a {display:flex;background:gray}
```

```html
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

or float and clear

```css
a {float:left;clear:left;background:gray}
```

```html
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

or even inline-block + width

```css
a {display:inline-block;width:100%;background:gray}
```

```html
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Upvoted ... and you missed one, so I added it to the answer list :)

Comment: @LGSon oh yes, did not think of that one at all :

Answer (score 3):

If you want to leave the anchor `a` to its default, you can use a pseudo element to break the line

```css
a::after {
  content:"\A";
  white-space: pre;
}
```

```html
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper semantic markup should be based on a list as follows:

```html
<ul class="redirects">
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
</ul>
```

With that markup, styles you need should be like below:

```css
UL.redirects,
UL.redirects > LI {
    margin:  0;
    padding: 0;
}

UL.redirects {
    list-style: none;
}
```

and, if you need links to be blocks:

```css
UL.redirects A {
    display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add this to your CSS file:

```
.redirects a {display: block;}
```

The CSS file should be linked in the head. Note that it is also possible to add this CSS to the body, like this:

```
<style>
    .redirects a {display: block;}
</style>
<div class="redirects">
    <a href="http://google.com">1</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">2</a>
    <a href="http://google.com">3</a>
</div>
```