# Using display: block with anchor tag

Tags: css

I have written this simple CSS. I am trying to understand why when I put `display: block` in the anchor tag, the width of the tag becomes the same as the `<li>` item. When I remove `display: block`, however, the width of the anchor tag is same as the text in it, as one would expect

```css
#menu ul {
  margin-left: -2.5em;
}

#menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  border: 2px black solid;
  background-color: gray;
  width: 20%;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
}

#menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  background-color: #EEEEFF;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px gray;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 2px;
  display: block;
  border: 3px solid #EEEEFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li> <a href="#"> Google </a> </li>
    <li> <a href="#"> Yahoo </a> </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: That's why inline and block elements are different. Block elements expand to the full width of their container -- inline elements don't

Comment: not sure why you gave a -1. Just tyring to understand a concept

Comment: I didn't, but thanks for assuming.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do you put a display:block on an "a" tag that is inside a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16643424/why-do-you-put-a-displayblock-on-an-a-tag-that-is-inside-a-list)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The display `block` will set as default `width: 100%`, if you wanna change it define the `width` in the css code.

When you remove the `display: block` in your code your anchor will use its default `display: inline`.

If you wanna use `display: block` and see your element like `inline` you can use `display: inline-block`;

Answer (score -1):

giving the a tag display:block will allow the element to occupy the full width of the div and also at this point  the padding and margin properties can take effect (padding and margin can't be applied on inline element as the a tag)

Comment: This answer doesn't add a different solution to the currently accepted answer, you should instead edit the accepted answer to improve it. New answers should directly explain why they differentiate from the existing answers of what context they may apply in.